# Enviar texto a Bloc de Notas (o cualquier programa ABIERTO)

Tags: delphi

Tengo abierta una ventana de bloc de notas en blanco, mi aplicación en Delphi y mucho entusiasmo, pero ahora debo **ESCRIBIR** en el bloc de notas el contenido de tres TEdit en un orden específico al momento de pulsar un botón. Ya me dediqué a buscar en el memorial del club, pero no encuentro nada medianamente aproximado a lo que requiero.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, es importante realizar preguntas en el sitio en base a el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado. No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

```
uses
  Clipbrd;

procedure LaunchNotepad(const Text: string);
var
  SInfo: TStartupInfo;
  PInfo: TProcessInformation;
  Notepad: HWND;
  NoteEdit: HWND;
  ThreadInfo: TGUIThreadInfo;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@SInfo, SizeOf(SInfo));
  SInfo.cb := SizeOf(SInfo);
  ZeroMemory(@PInfo, SizeOf(PInfo));
  CreateProcess(nil, PChar('Notepad'), nil, nil, False, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, sInfo, pInfo);
  WaitForInputIdle(pInfo.hProcess, 5000);

  Notepad := FindWindow('Notepad', nil);
  // or be a little more strict about the instance found
//  Notepad := FindWindow('Notepad', 'Untitled - Notepad');

  if Bool(Notepad) then begin
    NoteEdit := FindWindowEx(Notepad, 0, 'Edit', nil);
    if Bool(NoteEdit) then
    begin
      SendMessage(NoteEdit, WM_SETTEXT, 0, Longint(Text));

      // To force user is to be asked if changes should be saved
      // when closing the instance
      SendMessage(NoteEdit, EM_SETMODIFY, WPARAM(True), 0);
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    ZeroMemory(@ThreadInfo, SizeOf(ThreadInfo));
    ThreadInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(ThreadInfo);
    if GetGUIThreadInfo(0, ThreadInfo) then begin
      NoteEdit := ThreadInfo.hwndFocus;
      if Bool(NoteEdit) then begin
        Clipboard.AsText := Text;
        SendMessage(NoteEdit, WM_PASTE, 0, 0);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LaunchNotepad('test string');
end;
```

Comment: Considero que, en general, no es una buena práctica utilizar el portapapeles, pero si se debe realizar algo genérico que funcione con cualquier programa y el usuario está bien consciente de lo que ocurrirá, concedo este caso como válido, por eso va el +1, un saludo!

Comment: Tono, el detalle es que comencé a trabajar en el portapapeles para traspolar a trabajar con una aplicación que yo no hice..

Saludines.